# AppSync subscription to an external data provider using Websockets

Tags: websocket, subscription, aws-appsync

How can I setup a subscription to an external provider that provides me with streaming updates via Websockets or Kafka. I want the front to refresh in real-time based on data coming through the websocket or Kafka or Pulsar messages.

Comment: AppSync does the PubSub for you i.e fans out the messages to the subscribed clients via websocket https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html. Maybe it's better if you explain your use case and the place of Kafka?

Comment: Thanks. I thought that AppSync subscriptions was limited to DynamoDB streams. I will look at this page and see if I can figure out before I ask more questions.

Comment: So here are more specific questions. I have a data provider that provided me real-time updates using websockets. I have web based and mobile apps that will display this information in real-time. 

1) Do I connect the clients directly to the Websocket source and update data real-time on the application/mobile app?
2) Should I connect a backend to the websocket client and pass it through AppSync subscriptions so I do not need to store API keys on each client and can use the Cognito session to get data from AppSync that just works as a forwarder for the messages.

Comment: @SudeepAmin were you ever able to find a solution to your question?  I'm currently investigating the same scenario.